# How to set up bridged network with virtual machine and host with KVM (Virt-Manager)?

Tags: linux, ip, kvm, bridge

I'm trying to set up a bridged network so I can ssh into my KVM virtual machine. I haven't been able to find a clear cut guide online. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Then you need give IP address from IP network of your host server to virtual machine or make IP port forwarding on the host server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always found that the easiest way to do this, especially if you want the VMs to be *just another host on the LAN*, is to configure the host machine so that **its** configured interface(s) are bridges rather than the physical hardware.

e.g. if a system is configured to set up `eth0` as its main (or only) interface, then change it to:

- set up a bridge `br0` on interface `eth0`.
- comment out or remove all configuration that sets up `eth0`
- set up `br0` exactly the same as the old `eth0`, whether that is with a static IP address or a dhclient or whatever.

qemu/libvirt/kvm/etc should be configured to use `br0` rather than `eth0`.

The VMs should be configured to use `br0` (it will probably appear in the drop-down list as something like "**Bridge br0: host device eth0**")

Comment: Great, I got that working... how do I define the IP address of the VM though to ssh into it?

Comment: in the usual way - e.g. by configuring it with a static IP address, or with DHCP.   `libvirt` usually runs `dnsmasq` by default to provide DHCP service to VMs, or (if that's disabled) since the VM is on a bridged network (*just another host on the LAN*) of eth0 any DHCP server on that network segment will see and respond to DHCP requests from the VM.   I configure my ISC `dhcpd` to give fixed IP addresses based on MAC addresses for each VM (with a small pool of dynamic IPs for VMs I create for some short-term purpose).   Or a dhcp-relay can forward dhcp requests to another interface.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for your help :) I hope this post helps other people new to Linux servers.