# Host is getting an IP from a bridged device but a virt-manager VM is not

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, kvm, virt-manager

First, my question is similar to [How to set up bridged network with virtual machine and host with KVM (Virt-Manager)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386136/how-to-set-up-bridged-network-with-virtual-machine-and-host-with-kvm-virt-manag) but the marked answer does not work for me, and since the question is marked as solved, I thought it best to post a new question.

I will try to simplify my setup.

- I have a `host` with `eno1` (running Debian + KDE)
- I have removed all `eno1` interfaces
- I have created a bridged interface `br0` and added `eno1` as a slave
- I have virt-manager installed on `host`

Now:

- `host` is connected to `br0` and **does** get an IP
- a virt-manager `VM` is configured to use `br0` but it **do noes** get an IP

No matter what I try, I cannot get the `VM` to get an IP. How can I fix this?

Here are some screenshots. Ignore br1 as that was just me playing/testing.

The `br0` connection...

[image]

... with an Ethernet slave ...

[image]

... linked to `eno1`.

[image]

`VM` configured to bridged device `br0`

[image]

Comment: I was about to ask: "are you also running Docker?" but that's not needed, the screenshot tells you are. Can you try again with Docker disabled? ie: `systemctl disable docker` + reboot (the reboot is mandatory). Does it work better then?

Comment: @A.B Now it works -- the VM gets an IP. Do you know how to make it work with Docker enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker uses *iptables* to manage its containers, just like [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/) uses it too. But usually Docker doesn't play nice with other network-related tools running on the same system, for two reasons:

- [Docker loads](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/88744155b9e42bf402cf120c9b68b843476b5417/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L383) the [`br_netfilter` kernel module](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) that makes [*bridged* frames traverse *iptables*](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7) (instead of only *ebtables*).
- Docker also sets [*iptables*' default filter/FORWARD policy to DROP](https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/#docker-on-a-router)

  > **Docker also sets the policy for the `FORWARD` chain to `DROP`.** If your
  > Docker host also acts as a router, this will result in that router not
  > forwarding any traffic anymore. If you want your system to continue
  > functioning as a router, you can add explicit `ACCEPT` rules to the
  > `DOCKER-USER` chain to allow it.

The combination of these, and the fact that [`br_netfilter` does this as default behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719112/why-do-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-arp-ip-ip6tables-default-to-1), any bridge present on the system, be it related or not to Docker, inherits a default forward policy of DROP through *iptables*, in addition to whatever *ebtables* might do if also present: any forwarded frame gets dropped instead.

So all bridges handled by *libvirt* get affected: VMs get isolated because of Docker running. As quoted above, exceptions can be added (but should actually be inserted rather than added) to the `DOCKER-USER` chain rule created by Docker (but which can be created first by the administrator if needed). Merely adding rules to the `FORWARD` chain might not be enough because Docker always insert its rules before (but calls `DOCKER-USER` first).

To allow any non-Docker bridge to not be filtered by *iptables*, one could use one of the following choices:

1. match by IP address what is allowed to be forwarded. Won't be easiest to differentiate with DHCP using addresses such as 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255, they must also be added. For the IP LAN 192.0.2.0/24 that would be:

   ```
   iptables -N DOCKER-USER || true # doesn't matter if done before Docker or after (and thus already existing)
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s 192.0.2.0/24 -d 192.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s 0.0.0.0/32 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. or instead match by non-Docker interface

   Unless custom named, Docker interfaces are always named either `docker0` or `br-...`. Don't use the same naming convention and add exceptions for them.

   From *iptables* point of view, the bridged frames forwarded from the bridge ports *eno1* and for example *vnet0* (the tap interface for the VM) are presented as coming from the *br0* interface: the bridge port won't be seen, so the packet comes from *br0* and is forwarded to *br0*.

   Order matters. Stating the insertion index keeps a natural order for rules below just as if they had been added with `-A` (but they have to be inserted because of Docker adding a final `-j RETURN`).

   ```
   iptables -N DOCKER-USER || true
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -i docker0 -o docker0 -j RETURN
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i br-+ -o br-+ -j RETURN
   ```

   Allow `br0` and `br1`:

   ```
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 3 -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 4 -i br1 -o br1 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   Let's continue with other common names for libvirt and LXC (also an usual victim):

   ```
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 5 -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 6 -i lxcbr0 -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
   ```
3. or instead have *iptables* get some bridge information to do a decision

   Even if it appears more generic it should be avoided, because using the [`physdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#physdev) match module does load the `br_netfilter` kernel module to work if not already loaded, so will get this present even when not using Docker, while its goal is to protect oneself from Docker loading `br_netfilter`. It's a bit more powerful because it allows to distinguish frames that were bridged from packets that were routed (with a one-armed routing which happens to use a bridge as routing interface).

   Exceptions for Docker are still required since Docker does its own LAN filtering in its own chains. Anything non-Docker and bridged (rather than routed) gets allowed.

   ```
   iptables -N DOCKER-USER || true
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -i docker0 -o docker0 -j RETURN
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i br-+ -o br-+ -j RETURN
   iptables -I DOCKER-USER 3 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
   ```

Previous choices might not work with all possible cases, considering *libvirt* itself has rules in the FORWARD chain that might not work properly or might possibly be short-circuited by Docker's rules. Although *nat* rules, which are also affected are usually handled completely correctly for this case by *libvirt* (and by LXC).

4. Docker in a VM

   Don't mix Docker with any other networking tools, it will mess their behavior in presence of a bridge. Instead run Docker itself in a VM where it's properly isolated and won't affect the host, or other VMs and containers (eg: LXC) on the host. Then if this VM is itself bridged with the main network, as the current host's setup already allows, this won't change much to the external settings to reach its containers: Docker will just have its own separate IP address on the physical LAN rather than the host's.
5. other possibilities (requires kernel >= 5.3)

   Preload `br_netfilter` to be sure to get the *sysctl* settings available, and disable the system-wide setting for *iptables* with:

   ```
   modprobe br_netfilter
   sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
   ```

   and enable it back on select Docker bridges (possibly using a script running Docker commands to retrieve their names):

   ```
   ip link set dev docker0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1
   ip link set dev br-5039242381f0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1
   ```

   This will require to do actions on each new bridge created.

   An other way could be [Docker-in-Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) running itself in a container with just the global setting disabled (this setting is still enabled by default on new network namespaces...). This looks increasingly more difficult because of the additional management burden than running Docker in a VM.

I'd go for 4. (VM: avoids all possible Docker interference) or else 2. (keep it simple but good enough)

Note: everything written applies to IPv6 by replacing `iptables` with `ip6tables` above (including the `sysctl`). For *nftables* integration see this [*nftables* specific answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657545/nftables-whitelisting-docker) instead.

Comment: Oh, wow. I appreciate such a detailed response. I feel like 1-3 may also break at any time if there is some kind of update, right? So running on a VM seems easier....

Comment: Yes and I admit I must revisit 2: it's not possible to simplify into -i br+ -o br+. Eg: -i br0 -o br1 is not bridged but routed.

Comment: I am not sure what all that means. I don't know much about iptables and I don't really want to learn. I will go with option 4 unless I find a better one. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if this applies to LXC or LXD containers too? Could I get this to work if I created LXC/LXD containers on my Debian host?

Comment: No real idea with LXD (but I guess LXC being its backend it's just as LXC). If you mean: remove Docker completely and replace it with LXC (or LXD) then `br_netfilter` won't be loaded because LXC doesn't use it at all and other components on the system using bridges won't be affected anymore. There must be no iptables rule using `physdev` too, because that's an other cause of loading `br_netfilter` (workaround in 3. must be removed if it was in place).  **But** If you mean: is LXC or LXD affected by Docker just as libvirt, the answer is yes, as I wrote in parts 2. , 3. and 4. .

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of, not using Docker and using LXC/LXD for my containerization needs instead. Thanks!

Comment: I have this same problem. here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765935/kvm-vm-on-bridge-to-host-not-getting-ip-address.  But I do not have iptables service running. How can I check if there is traffic blocked?