# KVM VM on bridge to host not getting IP address

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, network-interface, kvm, bridge

I have a host with 4 ethernet ports. I want to assign eno1 to VM1, eno2 to VM2 and so on...

eno1, eno2 , eno3 and eno4 each have static IPs. I want VM01 to have the static IP of eno2. For that purpose I setup a bridge and added eno2 to the bridge. upto this point it looks ok.

After that I installed VM using cockpit. during install I let the config as default to enp1s0 (with DHCP for IPv4).

After install on boot up the interface did not get IP address. I am expecting eno2 IP which shows up on bridge after eno2 was added to bridge, should show up for this interface.

**on VM client**

[image]

**nmcli connection status**

[image]

[image]

**From KVM host: I believe the vnet0 came from VM install. relevant output below:**

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br2 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:67:7c:d6:07:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: br2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:67:7c:d6:07:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 123.112.147.147/26 brd 135.193.167.191 scope global noprefixroute br2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br2 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:e6:ef:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fee6:efb1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# bridge link show
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br2 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
22: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br2 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100

here is the xml portion from VM:

    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:e6:ef:b1'/>
      <source bridge='br2'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came to know that in a bridge:

1. physical NIC cannot have an IP.
2. bridge CAN have an IP - it is optional. If it has then physical host can be accessed using that IP. If not then, ppl cannot access phy host on the intfc/IP.
3. virtual NIC should have an IP (static or DHCP). When vNIC (or VM) is UP, then ping to that IP will respond. AND only VM will be accessible using that IP.

so I have following *only* on vNIC:

```
IPADDRESS
PREFIX
GATEWAY
DEFROUTE=yes
```